# Need Scroll Bar for Drop Down List populated by ng-options

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, angularjs

I have this code which populates the drop dopwn menu:

```
echo "<div class='form-group'>";
echo "<label for='show'>Show:</label>";
echo "<select class='form-control' id='filterText' ng-model='filterText' ng-options='show_name for show_name in filterList'>"; // Show Type Dropdown
echo "</select>";
echo "</div>";
```

[image]

I want to be able to only show maybe 8 options then be able to scroll down to see the rest. How do I go about doing this? When I adjust the height, it just adjusts the height of the actual field instead of the drop down size.

**This is not what I want:**

[image]

**TURNS OUT IF THE LIST IS LONG ENOUGH, IT WILL AUTOMATICALLY ADD A SCROLL BAR. THIS IS NOT ORIGINALLY WHAT I WANTED. IT WOULD BE EASIER IF THERE WERE 8 SHOWS SHOWN TO START WITH AND BE ABLE TO SCROLL THROUGH THE REST.**

Comment: Have you tried to add the attribute `size=8` in the html of the select?

Comment: @quirimmo Yeah, it just expands the actual field instead of giving the drop down area a scroll bar.

Comment: @JDo did you integrate it with the CSS overflow-y: scroll;

Comment: @quirimmo Yes. Just updated the question. As mentioned, it expands the actual field but it does give a scroll bar but I don't want it to increase the height of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<select onfocus='if(this.options.length > 8){ this.size = 8; }' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
</select>
<br>
<select onfocus='if(this.options.length > 8){ this.size = 8; }' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not a huge fan with how this looks but I suppose i'll use this for the time being. Thanks.

Comment: I know it is a little workaround but actually if you don't want to use CSS this looks like the easiest way to achieve what you need. If this fits your issue, please vote and accept is so that it can be useful for other people with the same issue too in the future

Answer (score 2):

```
 select {
            max-height: 300px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

This should do it for you. Adjust max-height as necessary.

Comment: Just tried this and this resizes the actual field and it doesn't add a scroll bar?

Answer (score 0):

HTMl:

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <label for='show'>Show:</label>
    <select class='form-control' ng-class="{scrollClass' : show_name.length > 8}"

    id='filterText' ng-model='filterText' ng-options='show_name for show_name in filterList'></select>
</div>
```

**ng-class="{scrollClass' : show_name.length > 8}"**

**CSS:**

```
 .scrollClass{
            max-height: 300px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

Comment: In your CSS you miss a . It should be .scrollClass

Comment: Your ng-class should be inverted too

Comment: @CodeMan This doesn't work event if I just put `ng-class='scrollClass'`

Comment: @J.Do : my point is when the results count more than 8 we apply the class to the div.

Comment: @CodeMan I'm still getting this even if I apply the code you wrote: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$parse/syntax?p0=%3A&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B)%5D&p2=23&p3=(show_name.length%20%3E%208%20%3A%20%22scrollClass%22)&p4=%3A%20%22scrollClass%22

Comment: Again: the issue is in the ng-class. It should be inverted. Class on the left, expression on the right.

Comment: try ng-class="{'scrollClass' : show_name.length > 8 }"

Comment: @CodeMan thanks. It's since the second comment I am trying to say it

Comment: @CodeMan Tried the inverted way but it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can this implement HTML/JS/CSS solution into Angular?

```css
 select {
    position:absolute;
 }
```

```html
<div class='form-group'>
  <label for='show'>Show:</label>
  <select size='1' onmousedown='if (this.options.length > 8){this.size = 8}' onchange='this.size = 0' onblur="this.size = 1" class='form-control' id='filterText'>

    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option>This is an option</option>
    <option>This is another Option A</option>
    <option>This is another Option 2</option>
    <option>This is another Option 3</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option B</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class='form-group'>
  <label for='show'>Show:</label>
  <select size='1' onmousedown='if (this.options.length > 8){this.size = 8}' onchange='this.size = 0' onblur="this.size = 1" class='form-control' id='filterText'>

    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option>Dr. Salunkhe</option>
    <option>Pregnancy</option>
    <option>COVID</option>
    <option>Opthamologist</option>
    <option>Physician</option>
    <option>Orthapedician</option>


  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider adding some text to support your code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 select {
    position:absolute;
 }
```

```html
<div class='form-group'>
  <label for='show'>Show:</label>
  <select size='1' onmousedown='if (this.options.length > 8){this.size = 8}' onchange='this.size = 0' onblur="this.size = 1" class='form-control' id='filterText'>

    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option>Physician</option>
    <option>Dr. Salunkhe</option>
    <option>Orthopedician</option>
    <option>Opthamologist</option>
    <option>COVID</option>
   
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65599430/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.